# Path changes with move to VPS

Tags: civicontribute, joomla, webserver

I have a civi site working from a subdomain on my main VPS account. I want to move the account to its own cpanel account, allowing the client full access to the site. However, I'm concerned about path changes and whether I need to change anything beyond what's in civicrm.settings.php, Resource URLs and cache. Is changing the BaseURL, etc. in settings enough to manage all absolute path references?

Thanks, 
Kate

Current: /home/sherida1/public_html/jgsny_restore

New: /home/jgsny/public_html/

Comment: Have you looked here? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/

Answer (score 2):

At least a couple times a month, I copy our live site over to the dev version, which means different paths. I just make sure I:

delete the templates_c directory and let it recreate itself

change the civicrm.settings.php file

check the directories page in CiviCRM: administer > system settings > directories

check the resource URLs page in CiviCRM: administer > system settings > resource URLs

clear caches and update paths: administer > system settings > cleanup caches and update paths

Running through all these steps always fixes any changes in my installation directory.